# Android can't find asset with Arabic in its name

Tags: android, arabic, android-assets, non-latin

### The problem

I can't open an Android asset that has Arabic letters in it.
`getAssets().open(name)` throws an IOException saying that the file is not found only if the asset has an Arabic letter in it, like د.

Note, I'm confident that my code works because English letters work. Please tell me if the problem is not clear.

Comment: AFAIK, resources file names should be English and small letters.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad Is there absolutely no way to write in something other than English?